# Count cells with certain values which appear between cells with other values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequence

I have one row in Excel with a number pattern (each number is in a different cell) like this.

```
1 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1
```

(My row has 300 cells).

Definition:

- I call a sequence of zeros between non-zero values "0 sequence".
- I call the non-zero value which marks the start and end of a 0 sequence the "mark value"

I want to calculate:

- Count for 0 sequence the number of 0. In this example above, the result is: 3, 2, 5, 8, 3
- Determine the smallest 0 sequence. In the example above, it is 2
- Determine the largest 0 sequence. In the example above, it is 8
- Determine the frequency of each 0 sequence. In the example above, it is:

  - Number of 0 sequence for the entire row with length 1: 0
  - Number of 0 sequence for the entire row with length 2: 1
  - Number of 0 sequence for the entire row with length 3: 2
  - Number of 0 sequence for the entire row with length 4: 0
  - Number of 0 sequence for the entire row with length 5: 1
  - Number of 0 sequence for the entire row with length 6: 0
  - Number of 0 sequence for the entire row with length 7: 0
  - Number of 0 sequence for the entire row with length 8: 1

I tried different Excel formulas like this one:

```
=ABS(MATCH(D13, B2:B11, 0)-MATCH(D14, B2:B11, 0))-1
```

This formula does not work for mark values ("D13", "D14")  with the same value. It also does not calculate it for more than one 0 sequence.

Any hint, preferably without VBA, would be appreciated.

Comment: The Google result I found are comparing cell values to a reference value, independent from other cell values (e.g. how many cells with the value x are in a row / colulmn / matrix? How many cells with a value larger / smaller than y are in a row / column / matrix?). I could not find a mechanism which considers dependencies between cell values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your values are in `A1:AA1` and outer values are <> 0:

The core of getting the right frequencies:

```
=FREQUENCY(IF(B1:Z1=0,COLUMN(B1:Z1)),IF(B1:Z1=0,"",COLUMN(B1:Z1)))
```

This would evaluate to an array of numbers > `3,2,5,8,3`

- Count for sequence (returned to `B3` in my example):

  ```
  =TEXTJOIN(",",1,FREQUENCY(IF(B1:Z1=0,COLUMN(B1:Z1)),IF(B1:Z1=0,"",COLUMN(B1:Z1)))
  ```
- Smallest sequence (returned in `B4`):

  ```
  =MIN(FREQUENCY(IF(B1:Z1=0,COLUMN(B1:Z1)),IF(B1:Z1=0,"",COLUMN(B1:Z1))))
  ```
- Largest sequence (returned to `B5`):

  ```
  =MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(B1:Z1=0,COLUMN(B1:Z1)),IF(B1:Z1=0,"",COLUMN(B1:Z1))))
  ```
- Count of each frequency (returned to `B5:B13`):

  ```
  =COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B$3,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.='"&ROW(A1)&"']"))
  ```

Or if you have not chosen to use `TEXTJOIN` for `B3`:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B$1:Z$1=0,COLUMN(B$1:Z$1)),IF(B$1:Z$1=0,"",COLUMN(B$1:Z$1)))=ROW(A1),1,0))
```

Drag down...

**Note:** All these formulas are array entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

[image]

As you can see I gave your query a little bit of my own twist through how I set up the returned values.

If you are willing to wait a while I'm sure someone can come up with something even simpler (maybe with Excel O365 and its DA-Functions)

Comment: Thank you @JvdV, very much appreciated.