# Count amount of consecutive ones (1s) in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in using excel vba. Would like to know a smart way to count amount of consecutive 1s in an array (or excel column) of zeros and ones.

Considering the following array:

```
A = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0];
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
Result = [4 4 1 5 5];
```

I know that in matlab it's easy to achieve with RunLength function, but in vba I can't find a similar function.

I tried adapting the following matlab code but cannot reach what I want due to proper use of find function.

```
clc
clear all
A = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0];
B = A(2:end);
C = A(1:end-1) - B;
D = find(C~=0);
Result = [D(1) D(2:end) - D(1:end-1) length(A)-D(end)]
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: this can be done with a formula see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778938/count-cells-with-certain-values-which-appear-between-cells-with-other-values/61780042#61780042

Comment: @ScottCraner - seems like a duplicate question to me. why not mark as such? (albeit one that may not have been *so easy* to locate)

Comment: OP is looking for vba not formula, otherwise I would @ScottHoltzman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub test()

    a = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
    a = Filter(Split(Join(a, ""), 0), 1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        a(i) = Len(a(i))
    Next
    Debug.Print Join(a)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Very dirty =)

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
Dim arr2 As Variant: arr2 = Evaluate("LEN({""" & Replace(Application.Trim(Replace(Join(arr1, ""), "0", " ")), " ", """,""") & """})")

End Sub
```

`Application.Evaluate` has a 255 char limit, but by the looks of it you won't quickly reach that.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty

```
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)

    Dim k As Variant
    Dim count As Long
    Dim lastk As Variant
    count = 1
    Dim coll As Collection
    Set coll = New Collection
    For Each k In arr
        If k = lastk Then
            count = count + 1
        Else
            If lastk > 0 Then
                coll.Add CStr(lastk) & "|" & CStr(count)
            end if
            count = 1

        End If
        lastk = k
    Next k
    If lastk > 0 Then
       coll.Add CStr(lastk) & "|" & CStr(count)
    end if
    For Each k In coll
        Debug.Print "Number: " & Split(k, "|")(0) & " Consecutive Count: " & Split(k, "|")(1)
    Next k
```